# How to get the specific columns with the highest value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

candidates ={'Name':['Lawrence', 'Justine', 'Kimberly'], 
                    
             'Points':[100, 50, 650]}
                        
df = pd.DataFrame(candidates)
# Who scored more points ? 
print(df[df.Points == df.Points.max()])
```

and the output of this code is

[image: click this to see the pic]

What I'm struggling with is that I want to print out only the name with highest value.

I want the result only: kim, without the column 'Name' as well

How to select the column with condition like select specific column with highest value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```py
print(df[df.Points == df.Points.max()])
```

with

```py
print(df['Name'][df.Points == df.Points.max()].to_list())
```

What this does is that it selects the row(s) with maximum points and selects the `Name` column and converts them to a list.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want the name of the person who scored the highest amount of points, you can do this

```
NameOfPersonWithMaxPoint = df.sort_values(by=['Points'],ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)['Name'][0]
print(NameOfPersonWithMaxPoint)
```

Explanation:

First, we use `sort_values` to sort the whole dataframe by points. Since we want the row with the highest points at the top, we specify `ascending=False`.

Now, we reset the index (and specify `drop=True` so that the index isn't inserted as a column), then get the first value in the 'Name' column, by specifying `['Name'][0]`.

If you wish to experiment with why the above works, try:

- Removing `.reset_index(drop=True)`
- Setting `ascending=True`

and see how it changes the results.